# Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I am trying to use this command to move my file to another folder using a cron job, but it doesn't work. Can someone point to an error in my code?

```
10 * * * *  mv -a /home/tect/Loco/* /home/tect/Public
```

`/home/tect` is my user folder, `Loco` is original folder which contains a file, and `Public` is destination folder.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is hard to debug. What's actually happening? Error messages? Any email with info from the `cron` daemon?

Comment: The way to debug it is to add `2>/tmp/foo.log` to the end of the line, and then check `/tmp/foo.log` for any error messages. Also add `-v` to the `mv` command so that something is printed if it does work. Try that and then [edit] your question to tell us whether `/tmp/foo.log` was created and, if so, what it contains.

Comment: I disable email feature using `MAILTO=""` due to no MTA installed

Comment: There is no Log created.Plus I have no Printer.

Comment: Apologies.I recheck my command.It seems there's a typo.

Comment: It says `mv: invalid option - - 'a' `

Comment: @mohdraimi "print" is write the log in the file, not print on paper :)

Comment: Ok,misunderstand statement.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an error:

```
mv: invalid option - - 'a'
```

This means that you implementation of `mv` does not know about the `-a` option that you're trying to use.

Since this option is not available in any implementation of `mv` that I have access to (and I therefore can't tell what it is you're trying to do), I can't give you any hints as to how to solve the issue other than re-reading the `mv` manual and rethink what you want to achieve.

Comment: If that the case,can you give an example of simple moving command for cron job.

Comment: @mohdraimi The same command, but without the `-a`?  Since it's not an option I recognize for the `mv` utility, I can't say exactly what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `mv` command works when you run it from the command line, the problem is probably due a missing or invalid PATH environment variable.

Typically `cron` logs its actions to `/var/log/cron` so that is where I would start troubleshooting.